# Keep sound from video playing in background

Tags: video

I have some serious trouble with VLC player on my device, so I have started using KMPlayer.

The only thing I miss from VLC is the ability to continue listening to the sound from videos even while switching to other apps or locking the screen.

Is there any good way to do this, either by modifying the system to make KMPlayer or any player do it, or by using another app?

Samsung I9305, rooted stock 4.4.4, Xposed Framework.

Comment: Does the answer have to be an app? If you're open to non-app answers (e.g. a way to make any video player do this using Xposed), your question is perfectly on topic here.

Comment: I thought this was a duplicate question at first but it seems like we [only have similar questions about YouTube specifically](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/96379/12442).

Comment: @DanHulme I'm certainly open to that Xposed module. I'll edit the question to reflect that. You can post it as an answer, including the name of the Xposed module. I will try it and accept your answer if it works.

Comment: I don't know if there is such a module (I don't use Xposed myself): it was just an example of a possible answer that's not "use app X". I wanted to check because often people post a question "I want an app to do this" when the answer is a combination of apps or a way of using their existing apps differently. Thanks for being open to that suggestion, and I hope someone does find an answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally use [MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details%3Fid%3Dcom.mxtech.videoplayer.ad), and it does what you say very well. It has support for locked screen audio playback, background play of audio from videos, pop-up videos and others. Downside is that the free version is ad-supported. Also, it needs a plugin for DTS/AC3 audio.

The background play setting is not enabled by default, and has to be enabled by the user, however, the background playback of audio is enabled by default.

<sub>Click images to enlarge</sub>

The background play notification:

[image: MX Player Background Play Notification]

The background audio playback setting:

[image: Background Playback setting]

Comment: @beeshyams, IMHO MX Player is the most compatible and featured Android video player. It's also popular, as a plus. It surprises me that you didn't know about it!